# month and date in two digits in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to add end date with javascript.

```
<head>
    <? $duration1 = $member_data['advt_duration']; //Using for var duration ?>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(function() {
                $('#start_date').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',timeFormat: "hh:mm tt"});
            });
        });

        function getdate() {
            var tt = document.getElementById('start_date').value;

            var date = new Date(tt);
            var newdate = new Date(date);
            var duration = '<?php echo $duration1 ;?>';
            //alert(duration);

            if (duration ==="One Month") {
                newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + 30);
            }
            if (duration ==="Three Months") {
                newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + 90);
            }
            if (duration ==="Six Months") {
                newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + 180);
            }
            if (duration ==="One Year") {
                newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + 365);
            }

            var dd = newdate.getDate();
            var mm = newdate.getMonth() + 1;
            var y = newdate.getFullYear();

            var someFormattedDate = y+ '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
            document.getElementById('end_date').value = someFormattedDate;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
From : <input name="start_date" type="text" id="start_date" style="border:1px solid #333;"/>

<input type="button" onclick="getdate()" value="Get End Date" style="background-color:#999; border:1px solid #333;"/>&nbsp;

To : <input name="end_date" type="text" id="end_date" style="border:1px solid #333;" readonly/>

</body>
```

**Now I am Getting START DATE in YYYY-MM-DD Format...But END DATE is Not getting in that format...**

e.g. If we set start date and suppose *var duration = "One Year"*...

**start_date = "2016-05-09" //09 May 2016**

Then 
getting

**end_date = "2017-5-9" Instead of "2017-05-09"**

Comment: There is a lot of wheel reinventing going on here, did you take  a look at moment.js?

Comment: Well what do you think that `y+ '-' + mm + '-' + dd` will do when `mm` is 5 and `dd` is 9?

Comment: @Pointy yes...when start month or start date is 1 to 9 , end date returning in one digit month or date...I want it in two digits...

Comment: So add `"0"` when `mm` is less than 10 ...

Comment: @Pointy I tried... if (mm.length < 2) mm = '0' + mm; and if (dd.length < 2) dd = '0' + dd;  but it doesn't work

Comment: Numbers don't have a `.length` property.  `if (mm < 10) mm = "0" + mm;`

Comment: @Pointy Ohhhhh Great.....It worked.....if (mm < 10) mm = '0' + mm;
    if (dd < 10) dd = '0' + dd; added after var mm, var dd var y.....Can u add this as an answer so I can Mark It as accepted answer....

Answer (score 0):

this will work

```
  mm = ( mm < 10 ) ? ( "0" + ( mm ).toString() ) : ( mm ).toString();
  dd= ( dd< 10 ) ? ( "0" + ( dd).toString() ) : ( dd ).toString();
```

Comment: Consider `mm = (mm < 10? '0' : '') + mm;`